# My thunderbolt 3 isn't working properly. Model Name: G5-793 | Part Number: NH.Q1HEG.003

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-c, thunderbolt

I am trying to connect an external display using thunderbolt 3 port, but it is not working, i tried uninstalling the thunderbolt 3 software, but it just doesnt detect any external display, how can i solve this?
When i go into the details of the thunderbolt software I see this

[thunderbolt details pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdFK9.png)

I am using a USB-C docking station which has 2 inputs, one VGA and one HDMI, I have another 2 screens, when I connect to any of the displays, my screen keeps going on and off for a min, then nothing happens, it detects the screen and i can see it in devices connected also in device manager, but nothing actually shows up, in the thunderbolt software, I dont see any detected devices, I tried connecting the my phone using the same cable, and works fine without any issues, so the cable should have no problems, any idea on how can i solve this issue?

EDIT: added thunderbolt specs
[Thunderbolt Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XPjk.png)

EDIT: [my laptop's user manual](https://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Document/User%20Manual%20W10/User%20Manual%20W10_Acer_1.0_A_A.pdf?acerid=636350254607444594&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=PREDATOR&Step3=PREDATOR%20G5-793&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6)

Comment: Provide us the specifications (in English) on the docking station

Comment: I edited my post with an image of the docking station, I just tried it on another laptop, and it work's fine

Comment: but doesn't it have to do with the thunderbolt's controller? cause it says it's unknown

Comment: That is unlikely. I have a suspicion that the problem is your Chinese docking station

Comment: Could be, but how come it's working properly on my phone and on another laptop?

Comment: Your phone isn’t connected by Thunderbolt alternative mode

Comment: I tried running it on another laptop, and it works, apparently, that laptop has 60Hz refresh rate screen, while this laptop has 75Hz, and the maximum supported refresh rate by the dock is 60Hz @1080p. Do you think there is a way to run the dock at a higher refresh rate? if not, do you have any recommendations on docks that support refresh rates higher than 60? (need it only for 2 screens, but could have more inputs though)

Comment: Hardware recommendations are out of scope